# Error during "selenium-standalone install" command

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, npm-install

Currently I am using the below commands for start the server (using Mocha framework) during second command am getting an error message. Please find the below and share your input

```
1. npm install selenium-standalone@latest -g
2. selenium-standalone install
3. selenium-standalone start
```

### Error Log: During "selenium-standalone install"

firefox install:

> from:
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.13.0/geckodriv
>   er-v0.13.0-win64.zip to:
>   C:\Users\xxuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone.selen
>   ium\geckodriver\0.13.0-x64-geckodriver
>   C:\Users\xxuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\selenium-standalone\bin\seleni
>   um-standalone:105
>           throw err;
>           ^ Error: Could not download https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/IE
>   DriverServer_x64_3.0.1.zip
>       at Request. (C:\Users\xxuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\se
>   lenium-standalone\lib\install.js:273:21)

---

Answer (score 0):

It is either an issue with google not having the file in the right place or selenium-standalone having the wrong url. If you go to  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.13.0/geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64.zip

it will download a zip file.

if you go to https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/IE%20DriverServer_x64_3.0.1.zip
you get:
    `NoSuchKey`The specified key does not exist.

The issue isn't firefox (gecko) driver it is internet explorer's driver.

Comment: Latest fully working is version 5.11.2

npm install selenium-standalone@5.11.2 -g

Comment: Thanks for your information. Yes you are correct its an issue with IE only. How to resolve this issue. In 1st command am always trying to install the latest one. Is there any other way to install locally to make it work. Thanks

Comment: selenium-standalone install --drivers.ie.version=3.0.0